# Using #pragma statement in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compiler-construction, razor, compiler-warnings, pragma

We have some files with the jQuery vsDoc includes like this for syntax help;

```
@if (false)
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

And it generates some annoying compiler warnings about unreachable code, I would like to wrap that statement with a [#prama warning](http://www.dotnetperls.com/pragma) but I cant figure out the syntax in Razor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@{ #pragma warning disable } 
@if (false)
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
}
@{ #pragma warning restore }
```

Works for me

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work...

```
@{#pragma warning disable}
```